# How to define aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm with multiple actions with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I used the AWS Console to set up a Cloud Watch alarm that will send my team a slack notification and reboot the affected EC2 instance, when the EC2 instance fails a StatusCheck fails.

Here's what the actions look like in the AWS console:

[image]

Now I want to write a terraform module that will set this up for me.  Here is what I have so far:

cloudwatch_metric_alarm/main.tf

```
locals {
    name = format("%s_ec2-instance-down-alarm", var.name_prefix)
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2-instance-alarm" {
    name = local.name
    description = var.alarm_description
    schedule_expression = var.schedule_expression
    tags             = merge(map("Name", local.name), var.extra_tags)
    alarm_name = local.name
    comparison_operator = var.comparison_operator
    evaluation_periods = var.evaluation_periods
    namespace = var.namespace
    metric_name = var.metric_name
    period = var.period
    statistic = var.statistic
    threshold = var.threshold
    dimensions = {
        InstanceId = var.instance_id
    }
    alarm_actions = [var.alarm_actions]
}
```

cloudwatch_metric_alarm/variables.tf

```
variable "extra_tags" {
  type    = map
  default = {}
}

variable "name_prefix" {
  type = string
}

variable "comparison_operator" {
  type = string
  default = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
}

variable "evaluation_periods" {
  type = number
  default = 1
}

variable "namespace" {
  type = string
  default = "AWS/EC2"
}

variable "metric_name" {
  type = string
  default = "StatusCheckFailed"
}
variable "period" {
  type = string
  default = "60"
}

variable "statistic" {
  type = string
  default = "Average"
}

variable "threshold" {
  type = string
  default = "1"
}

variable "instance_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "alarm_actions" {
  type = list(string)
}

variable "alarm_description" {
  type = string
  default = "This alarm will send a slack notification if the bastion host because unresponsive."
}
```

My question what do I pass in for `alarm_actions` in my parent module.  Here's the pertinent of the parent `main.tf`:

```
... other stuff ...

module "my-cloudwatch-metric-alarm" {
   source = "./cloudwatch_metric_alarm"
   alarm_actions = [???]
}

... other stuff ...
```

I have no idea what I am suppose to pass in as the `alarm_actions`.
What am I suppose to pass in?

Thanks!

UPDATE and NOTE to Self.

I was getting the error message

```
Error: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: Invalid use of EC2 action. An EC2 action can only be used if the alarm is monitoring an EC2 instance.
```

The cause of this error was this line were I misspelled `InstanceId`:

```
        InstatnceId = var.instance_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `var.alarm_actions` is already a list, so adding brackets around it like `[var.alarm_actions]` is going to create a list of lists, which is going to cause errors. You just need to pass it directly to the resource like:

```
alarm_actions = var.alarm_actions
```

---

For the first value you need to pass in that list, you need the ARN of the SNS topic you want to send the notifications to. You would find that in the AWS SNS console. If Terraform is managing the SNS topic for you, then you should have access to the topic ARN in Terraform already. Alternatively you could look it up via [a datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/sns_topic) by topic name.

For the second value, it is a special ARN that indicates to CloudWatch to reboot the instance being monitored. It looks like this: `arn:aws:automate:<region>:ec2:reboot`. For example if your infrastructure is in us-east-1 then the ARN would be `arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:reboot`. You could construct that dynamically in your Terraform code based on the region Terraform is deploying to by using the [aws_region datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/region) in the Terraform AWS provider.

---

Your final code may look something like this:

```
data "aws_sns_topic" "alerts" {
  name = "Your Topic Name"
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

module "my-cloudwatch-metric-alarm" {
   source = "./cloudwatch_metric_alarm"
   alarm_actions = [
      data.aws_sns_topic.alerts.arn,
      "arn:aws:automate:${data.aws_region.current.name}:ec2:reboot"
   ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Yep you are right about the alarm_actions parameter but now I get this error: `Error: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: Invalid use of EC2 action. An EC2 action can only be used if the alarm is monitoring an EC2 instance.`.

Comment: never mind. I misspelled "InstanceId" in the dimension parameter to the aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm resource. DOH!